# How can I autocomplete each parameter in a different way?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a function called load_pg, which is defined like this:

```
load_pg () {
    pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U $1 -d $2 $3
}
```

And I'm trying to autocomplete each parameter, with the following code:

```
#compdef load_pg
_arguments -s \
  "1::_ldpguser" \
  "2::_ldpgdb" \
  "3::_ldpgfile"

_ldpguser () {
  compadd $USER
}

_ldpgdb () {
  compadd $(cat config/database.yml | grep -i database | awk '{print $2}')
}

_ldpgfile () {
  compadd $(ls *.dump*)
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I press TAB. What am I doing wrong? I tried using code from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194558/auto-completion-in-zsh-on-3rd-parameter)

Comment: What's the shell you use?

Comment: I'm using z shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First hurdle: the syntax of an argument to `_arguments` is `n:message:action` where `message` is not allowed to be empty. If you add a message, you'll see some progress:

```
_arguments -s \
  "1:username:_ldpguser" \
  "2:database:_ldpgdb" \
  "3:dump file:_ldpgfile"
```

The next hurdle is that the auxiliary functions are defined after `_arguments` runs, so the very first time you complete the arguments you'll get an error message complaining that one of the functions doesn't exist. Define the functions before using them. Better, make the definition of the `_load_pg` function explicit and call it at the end of the autoloaded file. This looks clumsy, but it's the way most multi-function completion functions shipped with zsh are written.

```
#compdef load_pg

_ldpguser () {
  compadd $USER
}

_ldpgdb () {
  compadd $(cat config/database.yml | grep -i database | awk '{print $2}')
}

_ldpgfile () {
  compadd $(ls *.dump*)
}

_load_pg () {
  _arguments -s \
    "1:user:_ldpguser" \
    "2:database:_ldpgdb" \
    "3:dump file:_ldpgfile"
}

_load_pg "$@"
```

This gives you the core of the function. You'll then want to clean up the individual functions. At a minimum:

- `compadd $USER` seems pointless: if you only ever want to call the function with your user name, why not build it in? To complete user names, call `_users`.
- Command substitution substitutes at all whitespace. To split lines, use the `@` and `f` [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). You should also probably make your `grep` command more precise, and you may be able to combine it with `grep`.
- When you call `compadd` in an action from `_arguments`, pass it the contextual options in `$expl`.
- You may want to provide a description for completions with [`_describe`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fdescribe).
- `$(ls *.dump*)` is a convoluted way to write “`*.dump*`, and if there is no match, do something that depends on current shell settings”. [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), mmmkay? You could use `N` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to have an empty list of completions when there is no match. However, you should instead call [`_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005ffiles) which takes care of completing files in subdirectories, among other niceties.

```
#compdef load_pg

_ldpgdb () {
  compadd $expl[@] -- "${(@f)$(<config/database.yml grep -i database | awk '{print $2}')}"
}

_load_pg () {
  _arguments -s \
    '1:user:_users' \
    '2:database:_ldpgdb' \
    '3:dump file:_files -g "*.dump*"'
}

_load_pg "$@"
```